# How can I reduce the copy-paste code? Refactor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I refactor this piece of code so it contains less copy-paste code?

```
$("#hnv_4").click(function(e){
    manipulate(4);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#hnv_3").click(function(e){
    manipulate(3);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#hnv_2").click(function(e){
    manipulate(2);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#hnv_1").click(function(e){
    manipulate(1);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Can I use a loop here to minimize the code or maybe some jQuery?

I tried:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
 $("#hnv_" + i).click(function (e) {
    alert(i);

});
}
```

but at the end .. alert shows 5 always

Comment: Seems straight-forward; count from 4 to 1, capture the loop variable, use it to build the selector and call to `manipulate`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried this --->
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   $("#hnv_" + i).click(function (e) {
        alert(i);
  
    }); 
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: This question is a better fit for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes,

```
$("[id^='hnv_']").click(function(e) {
    var number = Number(this.id.split("_")[1]);
    manipulate(number);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Is e automatically passed in the callback or does that need to be specified as an argument?

Comment: @tymeJV I added the `Number()` part because the OP's code is passing a `Number` to `manipulate`, while `this.id` returns a string

Comment: @Ian -- Thanks for the edit, was just about to add the `event` param, didn't even realize the Number cast :D

Comment: Don't want to be nitpicking, but isn't it sub optimal performance-wise ? (the selector)

Comment: @EranMedan True, but it's probably better than looping and having to query the DOM multiple times.

Comment: @Ian Perhaps :) I'm tempted for a jsPerf , but I'm fighting the urge :)

Comment: I'd expect the browser to have a hash table of IDs, so looking them up directly should be fast. The prefix selector has to scan the entire DOM, doing string matches.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right; specifically since this has to do with the `id` attribute, it might be quicker to query the DOM a set number of times, instead of letting it scan all elements and matching the string. It might be different for other attributes

Comment: @EranMedan Actually, that would be a great idea. I think I'm wrong; Barmar convinced me (only because we're dealing with `id` though).

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah, it's no big deal, I just thought it would match up with the OP's code better :)

Comment: @EranMedan Here's the jsperf that I came up with: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-loop-vs-attribute-selector . I think it mirrors what we're talking about. So of course, I'm wrong :) I'm gonna try with a different attribute

Comment: @Ian -- 86% slower?!?! Lies!

Comment: @tymeJV Go back to the jsperf and tell me what surprises you in the results (I tested in more browsers). Make sure you look at each browser's results

Comment: @Ian -- Just surprised it was THAT much slower, other than that, just humoring you.

Comment: @tymeJV Haha no I agree. But look at IE8's results. `querySelectorAll` is faster. WTF

Comment: @Ian -- IE9 in IE8 compat mode is giving me `querySelectorAll` as 91% slower, hmm

Comment: @tymeJV I'm using a native IE8 :)

Answer (score 9):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="hnv" data-hnv="1">...</div>
<div class="hnv" data-hnv="2">...</div>
and so on
```

Then change the jQuery to:

```
$(".hnv").click(function(e) {
    manipulate($(this).data("hnv"));
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

If you want to do it with a `for` loop, you have to capture the index in closure, using an immediately-executing function:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    (function (i) {
        $("#hnv_" + i).click(function(e){
            manipulate(i);
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
    })(i);
}
```

See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for the explanation of why your loop doesn't work, and the extra function is needed.

Comment: Whilst this is probably a better way of laying out the HTML, it's not the correct answer given the question IMO.

Comment: @IanClark And that's why this shouldn't be accepted, but should be upvoted as a great/valid alternative :)

Comment: OK, I added the for-loop solution, you happy?

Comment: I like this much, much better than my comment; +1. IMO it should be accepted--it answers the *real* question.

Comment: @DaveNewton The question isn't "How can I change my HTML so my JavaScript doesn't need to be duplicated". I **agree** that this is what I wish people did more often (Barmar's first suggestion with the `data-*` attributes and common `class`) and I normally suggest it too, but the immediate question was just about condensing the JS. I know I know, we should always suggest the best practice...but since the OP was already storing the value in the `id`, I don't see a problem working off that

Comment: He asked how to refactor his code. Unless he specifically says that the HTML can't be changed, I consider them to go hand in hand, and refactoring the code includes the possibility of refactoring the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, he did **not** ask to refactor his code. He asked how to **minimize** his code. Check the edit history. I don't know why we're even arguing about this; I'll gladly take back my claim that this shouldn't be accepted. The "refactor" text was added by another person. And your answer assumes the `id`s aren't required. Maybe there's other code that needs them (like `<label>` elements). If so, why duplicate the number at the end of the `id` and put it in another attribute?

Comment: @Ian I know about the edit history. That's just because he didn't know the correct word for what he wanted.

Comment: @Ian There's no reason why he can't keep the IDs if they're required for some other reason. Although any time you see IDs like this, it means you're not using proper DRY principles. Probably all the other code that uses the IDs can be refactored to use the class instead.

Comment: @Barmar You read his mind and knew what he wanted? Maybe you know what he **should** want, and that's what this answer shows. In case you didn't see my last comment's edit, there's no reason to argue about this. I take back my "this shouldn't be accepted" because I don't know what I was thinking :) This is definitely the setup that should be used

Comment: @Barmar No you're right about the whole `id`/`class` thing. Sometimes I get caught up in what the OP has and forget about how I'd set it up so this type of problem wouldn't happen (like your first example).

Comment: @Barmar And not to be a pest, but I wouldn't suggest your second example how it is (although I know you were doing it to satisfy the first comment on your answer, and mine); I'd suggest that method, but not specifically putting any functions inside of the loop. It could easily be changed to not create functions in the loop, and use/reuse some instead. Not a big deal, I know it was an example, and it works fine as is

Comment: @Ian You have to create functions in the loop to capture `i` in the closure. There are other ways to write it, but they're effectively the same. If you think another method is preferable, post an answer.

Comment: The two comment threads in the two highly up-voted answers are why I really like SO . . . lots of stuff to be learned for those of us who want to dig a little deeper.

Comment: @Barmar This: http://jsfiddle.net/TeMRj/ is more or less what I meant. You're right, it accomplishes the same thing (which I understood), I was just saying I thought it was the better/cleaner way to do what you were showing. I wasn't trying to argue against your method, and I don't think it's substantial enough to create a new answer, because your answer and the accepted answer provide enough

Comment: @Ian I would use your method if the function were large, as embedding long functions is unesthetic to me. But for simple functions that would not be reused, I prefer to put them inline. What JS is really missing is something like Scheme/Lisp's `let`, which is syntactive sugar replacing the function definition but keeping its scope rules.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this should approximately do what you want to do.

```
for(var x=1; x<5; x++) { 
  $("#hnv_"+x).click(function(e){
    manipulate( e.target.id.substr(e.target.id.search('_')+1) );    
    e.stopPropagation();
  }) 
}
```

I'm doing the poor man's solution of scrubbing the "id" number out of the HTML id attribute when I:

```
e.target.id.substr(e.target.id.search('_')+1)
```

But if you are using jQuery, you may have the ".data" method where you could store the id in, and then not have to do that scrubbing hack. e.g.

```
for(var x=1; x<5; x++) { 
  $("#hnv_"+x).data("id",x).click(function(e){
    manipulate( $(e.target).data("id") );    
    e.stopPropagation();
  }) 
}
```

Not tested! feel free to correct me.